Finding the limit of an equation involving the Gaussian?
Here's a math competition problem that I've been stumped on 
I tried using L-Hopital's rule, I see how we get the equivalence via the M.V.T., but that approach doesn't seem to be working at all. I'm assuming there's another way to approach the problem (using integration by parts, or maybe the squeeze theorem?), but so far it's alluded me. Any help would be appreciated

Look at the Taylor expansion of the integral

Define $f$ given by $f(x)=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x} e^{-t^2}dt$.
This function is infinitely differentiable because the integrand is, and by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, $f'(x)=e^{-x^2}$.
From here, a simple computation tells us $$f(0)=0, f'(0)=1, f''(0)=0, f'''(0)=-2$$
By Taylor's Theorem, we may write $$f(x)=x-\dfrac{x^3}{3}+o(x^4)$$
From the definition of $c$, we have $$c(x)^2=-\ln\left(\frac{f(x)}{x}\right)$$
so $$c(x)^2=-\ln\left(1-\frac{x^2}{3}+o(x^3)\right)$$
Using the known limit $$\lim_{t\to 0}\dfrac{\ln(1+t)}{t}=1$$
we deduce $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\dfrac{c(x)^2}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}-\dfrac{\ln\left(1-\frac{x^2}{3}+o(x^3)\right)}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\dfrac{\frac{x^2}{3}+o(x^3)}{x^2}=\dfrac{1}{3},$$
and consequently $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\dfrac{c(x)}{x}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$$
